# plotfun - unable to replace Index (x-axis) with Date

Tags: plot

I want to plot the stock price time series for several stocks on individual plots. I've used plotfun but am unable to change to x-axis from Index to Date. I was wondering if I've missed something or is there better way to achieve this. Below is the code that I've created thus far and one of the two plotfun plots.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNU78.jpg)Thanks for your time and consideration in advance.

---

```
library("quantmod")
library("ggplot2")
library("BatchGetSymbols")
library("magrittr")
library("broom")
library("dplyr")
library("zoo")
library("xts")
library("tidyverse")
library("tidyquant")
library("TSstudio")
library("rlang")


GetMySymbols <- function(x) {
  getSymbols(x,
           src ="yahoo",
           from = "2010-07-01",
           to = "2016-06-30",
           auto.assign = FALSE)}

tickers <- c('TLS.AX','WOW.AX')

prices_Close <- map(tickers, GetMySymbols) %>% map(Cl) %>% reduce(merge.xts)

names(prices_Close) <- tickers

##plot.zoo(prices_Close, plot.type = 'multiple')

##plot.xts(prices_Close)

##plot.ts(df)

##df <- fortify(prices_Close)

mydf <- as.Data.frame(prices_Close)

plotfun <- function(col) 
  plot(mydf[,col], ylab = names(mydf[col]), type = "l")
par(ask = FALSE)
sapply(seq(1, length(mydf), 1), plotfun)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to the problem above:

```
for (i in 2:ncol(df)){
  print(ggplot(df, aes_string(x = "Index", y= df[,i])) + geom_line() + xlab("Date"))
}
```